# How to parse a String field to another type while importing from CSV in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, types, insert

I'm starting with SQL Server 2012 and I have a little problem.

I want to import data from a csv file to a table. One of the fields in the csv file is a `string` that it has only the values "Yes" or "No".

I've seen that there isn't a `boolean` type in SQL Server 2012, but there is a `bit` type instead of `boolean`.

The question I have is how to store in the table the value `1` when the `string` is "Yes" and `0` when the `string` is "No".

I've tried this:

```
BULK INSERT PRODUCT FROM 'C:\...\products.csv'
WITH (
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', 
   ERRORFILE = 'C:\...\errors.csv',
   TABLOCK)
```

I'm using `BULK INSERT` because I have thousands of rows, but I don't know if this is the best way or what alternatives I have (better alternatives).

Another way or suggestion to do it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either modify the data in the table by replacing `'Yes'` with `1`, etc or you put the data into a staging table and do the manipulation of data there. I would prefer the latter as it allows you to perform any other data clean up tasks.

As [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) suggests, you can perform the following which will load it into the desired table from your staging table and modify your `Yes/No` to bits:

```
INSERT dbo.Product(col1, col2, BITColumn)
  SELECT col1, col2, CASE col3 WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM dbo.StagingTable;
```

Comment: Ok, that could be right, +1. But is that the only way to do it? I think my case is quite common and maybe there is a better or more efficient solution to do it. Moreover, if I create a staging table, I should drop it when the load finishes or there is any way to create a temporal table to do this things?

Comment: You can use a temporary table for staging (which is common). You can manually drop it after your load is completed or it will be automatically dropped after your connection is closed.

Comment: Staging tables are useful for many reasons.  Data pulled from a csv could have *anything* in it.  Even if you are pretty damn sure it's clean, you are never sure until you load it.  Don't dump it straight into production tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  CASE col3
    WHEN 'Yes' THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    WHEN 'No'  THEN CAST(0 AS bit)
  END
INTO #my_temporary_staging_table
FROM OPENROWSET(
  BULK 'C:\...\products.csv',
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
) AS t(col1,col2,col3)
```